Yii2 UnknowPropertyException
I'm writing a PHP code that puts ingredients and recipes on a website, but when i try to use the URL for the form that adds an ingredient, it throws UnknowPropertyException claiming that there is no property named quantity, even though its declared in the model class.Here are the MVC classes:
Ingredient.php
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "Ingredient".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $quantity
 */
class Ingredient extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'ingredient';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'quantity'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['quantity'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
            'quantity' => Yii::t('app', 'Quantity'), 
        ];
    }
}

IngredientController.php
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Ingredient;

use Yii; 
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\HttpException;

class IngredientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $ingredients = Ingredient::find()->all();
        return $this->render('@app/views/site/index', ['ingredients' => $ingredients]);
    }

    

  
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $ingredient = Ingredient::findOne($id);
        if (!$ingredient) {
            throw new HttpException(404, 'O ingrediente não foi encontrado.');
        }
        return $this->render('view', ['ingredient' => $ingredient]);
    }


    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $ingredient = new Ingredient();
    
        if ($ingredient->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::debug($ingredient->attributes);
    
            if ($ingredient->validate()) {
                Yii::debug($ingredient->attributes);
    
                if ($ingredient->save()) {
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $ingredient->id]);
                } else {
                    Yii::error('Erro ao salvar o ingrediente: ' . print_r($ingredient->errors, true));
                }
            } else {
                Yii::error('Erro de validação do ingrediente: ' . print_r($ingredient->errors, true));
            }
        }
    
        Yii::debug($ingredient);
    
        return $this->render('create', ['ingredient' => $ingredient]);
    }
    


    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        throw new HttpException('501', 'É necessário implementar a VIEW dos Ingredientes.');
    }

    public function actionDelete()
    {
        throw new HttpException('501', 'É necessário implementar a VIEW dos Ingredientes.');
    }
}

Create.php
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;


$this->title = 'Create Ingredient';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Ingredients', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="ingredient-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($ingredient, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($ingredient, 'quantity')->textInput() ?>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
    
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

</div>


I tried changing the code, debugging, but it acts like there is no quantity variable, even though there clearly is. It should show the form page to add an ingredient but it always returns the error.

can you please try with below code and check ?
property integer $quantity change to @property int $quantity
